# Android paid app with subscription option

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase

I want my android app available at say price x one off, but also offer  app at lower yearly subscription price of y, can this all be done from Google play console, or do I have to manage this in code. Thanks.

There seems to subscription setting s in Google play console, and you can set a one off price, but I would like to offer both options.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm using Google Play Console product subscription and life time purchase as well and I will also suggest you to do the same if you have small scale app.
But keep in mind that the subscription cancelation ration is very high in Google Play Console since they offer 3 days free trial and most of the time users get their thing and then cancel the subscription.

On the other hand if you integrate your custom backend thing and do not use Google Play Console then you can have your own custom refund policies.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So if I used Google console for subscriptions , does this mean I don’t have to do code for this, and effectively let google manage the payments.

Comment: yup, for integration you need to code. here is the link to integration documentation

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate